# Looking for an ActiveRecord class similar to CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

I was wondering if anyone has stumbled upon a class similar to the `CodeIgniter` active record class?

I fell in love with this simple way of managing a database. I might think of building one myself but if there is one that would be a great help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an exact replacement for CI's awesome db class, but you can try [eZSQL](http://justinvincent.com/ezsql)